# Local and global scope in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dictionary with values having the same name. For e.g. mylist key should have a value of ['a', 'b'] 
The following code fails to replace the list with correct name.

```
mylist=['a', 'b']
yourlist=['x', 'y']
pw=dict()
for mysheet in ('mylist', 'yourlist'):
    pw[mysheet] = mysheet

pw
{'mylist': 'mylist', 'yourlist': 'yourlist'}

# expected result
#{'mylist': ['a', 'b'] , 'yourlist':  ['x', 'y']}
```

Does the for loop has local and global scopes just like functions?

Comment: what are you trying to do? You are passing a tuple of strings to for loop actually.

Comment: @karthikr no, not what the OP wants. To OP: why would you expect what you expect? `mysheet` inside the loop refers to the string not list.

Comment: See [Resolution of Names](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names). *When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope.*

Comment: Whenever you are trying to get one thing, in your case the variable name, to mean two things, it is a sign of bad coding and will lead you to problems later on. Don't use _meta_-variables, variables that mean something other than what they are representing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure of your usecase. In general this is not a very good coding pattern to follow

However, One way you can achieve this, is using the [`locals()` context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)

Basically, you would do `pw[mysheet] = locals()[mysheet]` inside the loop

DEMO

```
>>> mylist=['a', 'b']
>>> yourlist=['x', 'y']
>>> pw = {}
>>> for mysheet in ('mylist', 'yourlist'):
...     pw[mysheet] = locals()[mysheet] 
... 
>>> pw
{'yourlist': ['x', 'y'], 'mylist': ['a', 'b']}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should implement it.

```
for name, mysheet in ('mylist', mylist), ('yourlist',yourlist):
    pw[name] = mysheet
```

Also, you were passing string tuple, not actual variables.

As mentioned by [karthikr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628832/karthikr), you can also make use of `locals()`. But please note that the name that gets resolved, checks *current* namespace.

Comment: No, `dict` not only takes `str` as key but any non mutable object, for instance: `int`, `tuple`, `frozenset`…

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Totally forgot. Thanks for notifying the err. :)

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the local global question and focusing on your desired output, you could do the following if you don't mind refactoring your input data (variable assignment) pattern like this:

```
mylist=['mylist',['a', 'b']]
yourlist=['yourlist',['x', 'y']]

pw=dict()

for item in (mylist, yourlist):
    pw[item[0]] = item[1]

print(pw)
```

This way, with your desired key as `index 0` of your input list item, and your desired value list as `index 1`, it's a simple task to add your key:pair to the `pw` `dict`.